# How can I use with JS/CSS/HTML5 animation to get flash like animations? eg a PagePeel

Tags: javascript, animation, html

Specifically, I am talking about a decent "realistic" looking page peel from one images to the next in a set. This sort of technology will be vital to the success of Apple's new anti-flash, pro HTML5 push. Flash excels at complex and robust animations. Is it possible to create the same effects using only HTML5/JS/CSS today?

I found this JS VectorGraphics library:

http://www.netzgesta.de/curl/

but I am not sure how practical it is for animation.

Comment: By the way, how will a "page peel" be vital in the success of Apple's new anti-flash push? lol.

Comment: In addition to ItzWarty's comment, why is this push labeled as new? This is very, very old news! And anyway, a feature only used in some below average websites won't be a vital feature for Apple, never.

Answer (score 1):

For page flipping [which is basically image distortion] you would probably want to look into context.getImageData(x, y, w, h);
http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#pixel-manipulation